# Redirect not working correctly, 2> /dev/null becomes 2 > /dev/null and stderr doesn't get redirected

Tags: unix, redirect, xterm

I am hoping someone can help me figure out what setting I might need to overwrite. I am working on a Unix terminal server, running a Linux Xterm linux shell. Everytime I use a command like `grep "blah" 2> /dev/null` at the shell prompt, the command is run as `grep "blah" 2 > /dev/null` and needless to say the redirection fails.
xterm version is X.Org 6.8.99.903(238)

I can not update or install anything, this is a locked down production server.

Thanks for any help and illumination on the topic, it is making my grep useless at high directory levels with recursion.

Comment: A minor note, this is csh, when I switch to something like ksh the redirect works correctly... is this perhaps an idiosyncrasy of csh?

Comment: did you try grep "blah" 2>/dev/null instead of grep "blah" 2> /dev/null (note the blank space between > and /)

Comment: Hi Sai, ya, as soon as I saw how I typed my command out and went and verified that it doesn't matter, apparently csh takes 2>/dev/null and produces 2 > /dev/null... but we have a winner below, thanks for the input though :)

Comment: "*A minor note, this is csh*" -- That's not a minor note, that's the cause of your problem. `xterm` is just a terminal emulator; it's not a shell. `csh` is the shell, and it's what interprets the commands you type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's Bourne shell syntax, and it doesn't work in c-shell.

The best you can do is

```
    ( command >stdout_file ) >&stderr_file
```

Where you get stdout to one file, and stderr to another. Redirecting just stderr is not possible.

Comment: oh man, thank you. I am not used to working in csh. Sadly bash isn't something I get on this server. Thanks again, this has been driving me nuts since I started working on this server.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, you say "A minor note, this is csh".  That's not a minor note, that's the cause of the problem. `xterm` is just a terminal emulator, not a shell; all it does is set up a window that provides textual input and output. `csh` (or `bash`, or ...) is the shell, the program that interprets the commands you type.

csh has different syntax for redirection, and doesn't let you redirect just stderr. `command > file` redirects stdout; `command >& file` redirects both stdout and stderr.

You say the system doesn't have bash, but it does have ksh. I suggest just using ksh; it will be a lot more familiar to you. Both bash and ksh are derived from the old Bourne shell.

All (?) Unix-like systems will have a Bourne-like shell installed as `/bin/sh`. Even if you're using csh (or tcsh?) as your interactive shell, you can still invoke sh, even in a one-liner. For example:

```
sh -c 'command 2>/dev/null'
```

will invoke `sh`, which in turn will invoke `command` and redirect just its stderr to `/dev/null`.

The purpose of an interactive shell is (mostly) to let you use other commands that are available on the system. `sh`, or any shell, can be used as just another command.